# Graph-theory exercise

Tags: graph-theory

The picture below shows a graph connecting the cities А, Б, В, Г, Д, Е, Ж, И, К.

[image]

On each path you can only move only in direction of the arrow. How many different ways are there from city A to city K?

I understood that this exercise is from graph theory. Please tell me how I can solve exercises like this.

P.S. Sorry for my poor English. It isn't my native language. I would be very grateful if you would mention errors in my English.

Comment: Since you invited correction, I took the liberty of polishing up the English when I added the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Work backwards from К to А. There is only one way to reach К from И.  This gives you two ways to reach К from Д. Continue like that.

Comment: This way take away a lot if time, which I have not much. Isn't there any formulae,etc. for solve it

Comment: @skeeph, it does not take a lot of time. There is no guessing, just attach the correct numbers to each vertex and the number for a given vertex is the sum of the numbers of the vertices that are directly reachable from it.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is nothing more than a clarification to lhf's answer. Label the vertices as follows:

[image: labeled version]

Continue backwards as I've done with the first few. For each vertex, follow all the forward arrows one step, and add up the numbers at each end.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: The next vertex to label is В because all edges from it lead to labeled vertices.

Comment: I guess this must have been a homework problem with a very close deadline, for the op to just disappear like that (and of course based on the above comment).

Comment: Disappearing is common here. We just carry on...

Answer (score 0):

The adjacency matrix of this graph can be written:
$$A:=\left(\begin{array}{ccccccccc} 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{array}\right)$$
where the first index represents the leftmost vertex (call this $1$), and the last index represents the rightmost vertex (call this $8$).

The number of walks from $A$ to $K$ in $k$ steps is $A^k(1,8)$ (the entry in cell $(1,8)$ of $A^k$).  Hence the total number of walks from $A$ to $K$ is $$\sum_{k \geq 0} A^k(1,8).$$

In this case, $A^6$ is the all-zero matrix (and consequently $A^k$ for $k \geq 6$ is the all-zero matrix), so the total number of walks from $A$ to $K$ is $$\sum_{0 \leq k \leq 5} A^k(1,8).$$  We can compute this on the computer as $13$.