# graph-theory task

Tags: graph-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Graph-theory exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148703/graph-theory-exercise)

The picture below shows a graph connecting the cities А, Б, В, Г, Д, Е, Ж, И, К.

[image]

On each path you can only move only in direction of the arrow. How many different ways are there from city A to city K?

I understood that this exercise is from graph theory. Please tell me how I can solve exercises like this.

P.S. Sorry for my poor English. It isn't my native language. I would be very grateful if you would mention errors in my English.

Comment: Your English is quite understandable - but I couldn't help you with uploading the picture. Are you sure this is a working link?

Comment: Где З? ;-)$\quad$

Comment: @Ilya: Extra blank space after ‘http://’ $-$ never mind, I see that someone got it.

Comment: You can try to work backwards from city K.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s like the earlier problem. Work backwards from К: the only way to get there directly is from Е. Е can only be reached directly from В and Г. Г can be reached only from А, while В can be reached from Б or А, and Б can be reached only from А. If you backtrack from К to А, the first step must be to Е. After that you have two choices, В and Г. If you go to В, you have three choices: directly to А, Б to А, or Г to А. Thus, there are three routes back through В. If you go instead to Г, you have no further choices: you can only go to А. Thus, there are altogether four routes:

$$\begin{align*}
&\text{А}\rightarrow\text{Г}\rightarrow\text{Е}\rightarrow\text{К}\\
&\text{А}\rightarrow\text{В}\rightarrow\text{Е}\rightarrow\text{К}\\
&\text{А}\rightarrow\text{Б}\rightarrow\text{В}\rightarrow\text{Е}\rightarrow\text{К}\\
&\text{А}\rightarrow\text{Г}\rightarrow\text{В}\rightarrow\text{Е}\rightarrow\text{К}
\end{align*}$$

When you trace back, you see that only part of the graph actually matters:

```
                 Б  
                / \  
               /   \  
              А-----В  
               \   / \  
                \ /   \  
                 Г-----Е-----К
```

(All arrows here are understood to point from left to right.)

Comment: How many ways are there,tell me please?

Comment: @skeeph: I did: there are three.

Comment: Are you sure? This is very important for me

Comment: And $\text{А}\rightarrow\text{Г}\rightarrow\text{B}\rightarrow\text{Е}\rightarrow\text{К}\\$ too, so 4 path. This question is exactly equal to the earlier one, just check the other suggested solution: topological sort + go backward keeping the number of possible solution starting in a point, with the recursion $N(A) =$ sum over A childs

Comment: @skeeph: Sorry, skeeph: I was working from memory and accidentally miscounted. It should be four ways.

Comment: @carlop: I didn’t feel like tracking down the earlier problem to see how close they were. The miscount was the result of typing without having the picture in front of me.

Comment: My apologies, I was trying to say that @skeeph can have learnt from his previous answer, trying to understand how to calculate the solution for the general problem, istead of posting a different question for an almost equal problem.

Comment: @carlop: No apologies needed!

Comment: At this moment a have a disadvantage of time, and it is very important to solve this. Please, help me

Comment: @skeeph: I gave a complete solution. What part of it do you not understand?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the graph is acyclic.

Let $P(v)$ be the predecessors of $v$ (i.e. $P(v) = \{u : (u, v) \in V\}$).

Let $n_u(v)$ be the number of ways of reaching $v$ from $u$, where we define $n_u(u) = 1$.

Then, assuming no duplicate edges, $$n_u(v) = \sum_{w\in P(v)} n_u(w)$$

This is easily proven by induction over a topological sort of the vertices.